# Is there a function to get the next 10 rows for Sqlite3?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, asp-classic

I would like to displaying the next `5 rows` of my Sqlite table using `button(<)` pre 5 or `button(>) next` 5 of my row.

I read on the sqliteWebSite `sqlitetutorial` a function call's `Rank`.
It's a little bit difficult to understand for me how that will work.

It will be very helpfull if i get an easy example.

Comment: SQLITE supports both OFFSET (from where) and LIMIT (maximum records) SQL clauses.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results is useful reading.

Answer (score 0):

As rAndom69 mentioned, you will want to combine the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` keywords.
`OFFSET` tells Sqlite to skip the first `x` number of rows, while `LIMIT` tells it to return the next `y` number of rows.

For example, if you wanted to start at the 100th row of your table and return the next 10, you would do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

The RANK() function is a window function that assigns a rank to each row in a query’s result set. The rank of a row is calculated by one plus the number of ranks that comes before it.

```
SELECT
 Val,
 RANK () OVER ( 
 ORDER BY Val 
 ) ValRank
FROM
 RankDemo;
```

For More information show this link :

http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-rank/